# How can I handle multiple login portals with different authorization rules with JWT auth in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, authorization

Backstory: We have an application that uses JWT tokens with Role claims for each user. Users will be authorized by Role on controller level with `Authorize(Policy = "Some policy")`  attribute. `User` is connected to `Organisation`. When logged in, data about the Organisation is sent to the User and presented on frontend.

New request: Client wants to have same User account as a part of different Organisations. After login, frontend will receive User data as well as IDs of all Organisations it is part of. We are controlling login portals by selecting the Organisation from the dropdown in header.

User can have different authorization rules based on organisation it is part of. For example:
`User A` is part of `Organisations` `B` and `C`. There is an endpoint `getOrgData(int orgId)` and `updateOrgData(OrgDTO dto)`. `User A` is admin in `Organisation B`, so they should have access to both endpoints, but they are only employee in `Organisation C` and they should NOT have access to update endpoint for that Organisation.

We tried implementing multiple access tokens with different Role claims for all associated Organisations. We would then switch the token in state, when User switches portal. This is not secure enough, because User can find JWT tokens in local storage, and make a request via HTTP client with token with higher privileges.

Is there a way to better secure this approach, or do something else?

We could send `orgId` and `userId` on every request and query the database in controller, then throw 401 if `User` is not associated with `Organisation`, but we would like not to make our controller code dirty. Is there a way to achieve this with .NET Authorize attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a service like Duende IdentityServer inside your organization and through it let users authenticate with external services. This is called federated authentication.

Then all your internal services need to trust only one service.

Like this picture:
[image]

With this approach, you can internally have one token/role/claims structure and   this will simplify your internal application development.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking of it, but we had to make some sacrifices in estimation since it is a big feature, and we need to tackle a lot of changes in all parts of the system.

I wanted to find a 'non-ideal' solution for now, and implement IS somewhere down the line. The more I think about the solution though, I am starting to think it would be better to just try and get more time and implement it now.